# Linux : Ignoring a signal inside a signal handler, ignoring all such successive signals

Tags: c, linux, signal-handling

I have a simple program to demonstrate signal handling in C for Linux. I just complicated it for experimenting..

```
void sigquit(int signo)
{
    printf("Recieved signo : %d\n",signo);
    signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN);
}

int main()
{

    /* register the signal handler */
    if(signal(SIGQUIT,sigquit) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("Error handling SIGQUIT signal");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(;;);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output :

```
^\Recieved signo : 3
^\^\^\^\^\^\^\
```

whereas I was expecting this :

```
    ^\Recieved signo : 3
    ^\Recieved signo : 3
    ^\Recieved signo : 3
    ^\Recieved signo : 3
```

Why only first time my handler was called and not further. I expected the signals to be first coming to the main thread and then being passed to the handlers.

Comment: So what's the idea behind this line `signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN);` though? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_IGN);

From your signal handler, you told your program to ignore any further cases of the signal happening. As a result, as you send the signal again, it is ignored, just like you told it to.

Comment: The confusion is probably due to my understanding. Till now, I am of the view that as the program starts with `main()`, it sees that I want to register `sigint()` as the handler. So, it (not sure whether compiler or at runtime) register `sigint` to be called everytime the signal comes. What is inside `sigint()` is irrelevant.  This might help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/how-signals-work-internally. I am exploring it more to get the working clear.

Comment: "*What is inside sigint() is irrelevant.*" Why? :-S @InsaneCoder Try putting `int i = 0; i /= i;`  inside the handler. :-)

Comment: @InsaneCoder you make it sound like the compiler is clairvoyant. That is not the case. Your program gets executed one command at a time. Once a signal handler has been registered, and until another instruction is given, any time a signal is received the handler is called, and gets executed one command at a time. You placed code inside your handler to stop that, and the system, indeed, stopped.